# What does it mean when I "cannot convert X** to X*" in a "new" assignment?

Tags: c++

In running Ubuntu and the g++ compiler I keep getting the same error from this code.

```
 myClass *arr;
 arr = new myClass*[myClassSize]; // line 24
 for(int a = 0;a<myClassSize;a++) 
   arr[a] = new myClass;
```

Here is the error:

```
cannot convert 'myClass **' to 'myClass *' in assignment
```

The problem was on line 24.

Comment: That edit to the question changes things completely.

Comment: Not especially. I think it's fairly clear what the code is trying to do (and hence the problem and fix). The error message isn't even needed.

Comment: Mark, I'm not sure which edit you're talking about, but the only edit that really changed anything was the first one, by Litb. He *fixed* the code formatting, which originally didn't have enough asterisks because some of them were interpreted for italic formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an extra `*` in the declaration of `arr`:

```
myClass** arr;
```

You seem to be trying to make an array of pointers, but `type*` is just a pointer to `type` / array of `type`.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `arr` as a pointer to a myClass.  `arr[a]` is a dereference; it's the same as `*(arr+a)` which is a reference to myClass, not a pointer.

Answer (score -2):

It says what it means you are trying to assign myClass ** to myClass * which isn't allowed without a cast.  From the looks of it the line of code in question should read

```
arr = new myClass[myClassSize];//note the lack of star
```

That would create an array of myClass objects.

There is a certain amount of ambiguity between arrays and pointers in c++ so in this case the array returned by new is already capable of being assigned to a pointer.

if you want to make a array of pointers then you need to double the star on the def of arr to make a pointer to pointers of myclass.

Comment: No, the questioner is trying to put myClass* (the result of 'new myClass') into the array in the loop, so it's much more likely that myClass\** is what's needed.